# Changing the encoding of a single character in a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, character-encoding

I'm trying to create a script that will change the encoding of a single character in a string:

```
import random
import chardet


def tamper(payload):
    data_range = range(0, len(payload))
    accepted_encodings = ["iso-8859-1", "iso-8859-15", "utf-8", "ascii",
                          "iso-8859-2"]
    tampered_payload = []
    for i, char in enumerate(list(payload)):
        if i == random.choice(data_range):
            tampered_payload.append(char.replace(char, char.encode(random.choice(accepted_encodings))))
        else:
            tampered_payload.append(char)
    return ''.join(tampered_payload)
```

When I run this through `chardet.detect(c)` it outputs the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for c in tamper("SELECT * FROM *"):
        print chardet.detect(c)

{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
```

Now I know that this script is not guaranteed to change the encoding in a string due to the random function, but why is it that no matter what I do and even if the character has been re-encoded using one of the accepted encodings, it always outputs as `ascii`, does python always convert the characters to ascii in their strings?

---

I tried encoding with `codecs` as well:

```
import random
import chardet
import codecs


def tamper(payload):
    accepted_encodings = ["iso-8859-1", "iso-8859-15", "utf-8",
                          "iso-8859-2"]
    test = "string"
    to_encode = random.choice(accepted_encodings)
    print to_encode
    codecs.encode(test, to_encode)
    print chardet.detect(test)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tamper("SELECT * FROM *")
    # <= {'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
```

It seems to do the same thing, which is leading me to believe either, A) I'm an idiot and am missing something (mostly likely case) or B) This is an issue with `chardet` itself.

Comment: All of your encodings include ASCII as a subset.  As long as your original characters are all within the ASCII range, no encoding changes them at all.  (I wouldn't trust chardet on individual characters, anyway - that's not enough data to identify a particular non-ASCII encoding.)

Comment: @jasonharper So no matter what I "encode" them to, the subset always takes precedence over the encoding?

Comment: It's not a matter of precedence, it's the fact that most encodings agree with ASCII on how the basic letters/digits/etc. are represented: all of them encode "A" as character 65, for example.  It's the characters not commonly used in English where encodings differ - accented vowels, letters from other alphabets, specialized symbols, and so on.

Comment: @jasonharper So is there a way to encode only one character of a string and figure out if it worked successfully or not?

Comment: The codec would raise an exception if it wasn't able to encode a particular character.

Comment: @jasonharper Okay so then if I'm understanding you correctly, the characters are indeed "encoded" but when run through `codec` it's outputting `ascii` as the encoding because all the characters ords match with ascii, correct?